# Colorpicker issue with iframe in IE

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a contenteditable div, in which you can write something and, upon clicking on a button, an iframe opens. There is a colorpicker, by which the content font color can be changed.

It is working for FF and Chrome. My issue is that it is not working in IE. The problem is when I select the content to change color and then click on the iframe, the content has lost its focus, so the font color could not be changed. Please give me the solution of this problem.